# Detect if a reactive form is not dirty anymore after typing and erasing with Angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

It was easy to detect when a form is changed and is dirty:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    console.log(this.form.dirty);
  });
}
```

But now I need to know when the form has one of its fields erased and cleared and change the form back to not being dirty.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// To remove the control
if (this.form.get('controlName')) {
   this.form.removeControl('controlName');
   this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```